# Extracting columns from a dataframe into new dataframes by string contained in column name

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, for-loop

I have a dataframe which shows country power generation and load data (data can be downloaded from https://data.open-power-system-data.org/time_series/2019-06-05 and I am working with the 60 minute set). From this datafeame I want to extract columns related to each country in the dataset and create a new dataframe for each country and assign the dataframe the abbreviation for the respective country.

Up to now I have read in the raw data and got a list of unique countries from the column headers in the dataframe and saved them to a list called abbv.

I am trying to use the abbv list to create a dataframe for each abbreviation (each i in abbv) and populate the created dataframes with columns from the original dataframe which contain the abbreviation (i in abbv) for each country.

I have tried a for loop up to now, but am not quite sure if this is the correct method or if I am attempting to use the loop in the correct way. Any help would be appreciated. I am stuck on the nested for loop and not sure where to go from there - I know the code does not run below as is, I have left errors to try to explain my thought process to solve this problem. Thanks.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#read in
data_1h = pd.read_csv('/Users/xx/Downloads/opsd-time_series-2019-06-05/time_series_60min_singleindex.csv')

#get country abbreviations
abbv = [(i[:2]) for i in data_1h.columns]
abbv = pd.unique(abbv)

#create dataframe for each country
for i in range(len(abbv)):
    for i in abbv:
        i = pd.DataFrame()
        columns = [col for col in data_1h.columns if i in col]
        i = {columns: data_1h.column}
```

Comment: I would use a dictionary of dataframes and your keys could be  your country abbv instead of creating new variables for each dataframe.

Comment: I had not thought of that, but will give it a go. I've never created a dict of dataframes before, but after a quick search I see your point. How could I then populate each respective dataframe with the correct country date from the initial dataframe based on abbv? I have tried to use [col for col in data_1h.columns if i in col] hoping that the i in col would be recognised as a string

Comment: How about ```dict_of_dfs = {col[:2]: df.loc[:, col] for col in df.columns}```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion would be to split the column headers on the first "_" character and then turn this into a multi-level index that has the country abbreviation as the first level. You can then either (1) split each dataframe out individually or (2) just select whichever country you want as you normally would with any other dataframe.

```
In [3]: df.head()
Out[3]:
                                               AL_load_actual_entsoe_power_statistics  ...  UA_west_load_forecast_entsoe_transparency
utc_timestamp        cet_cest_timestamp                                                ...                              
2004-12-31T23:00:00Z 2005-01-01T00:00:00+0100                                     NaN  ...                                        NaN
2005-01-01T00:00:00Z 2005-01-01T01:00:00+0100                                     NaN  ...                                        NaN
2005-01-01T01:00:00Z 2005-01-01T02:00:00+0100                                     NaN  ...                                        NaN
2005-01-01T02:00:00Z 2005-01-01T03:00:00+0100                                     NaN  ...                                        NaN
2005-01-01T03:00:00Z 2005-01-01T04:00:00+0100                                     NaN  ...                                        NaN

[5 rows x 391 columns]

In [4]: df.columns = df.columns.str.split('_', n=1, expand=True)

In [5]: df
Out[5]:
                                                                               AL  ...                                     UA
                                              load_actual_entsoe_power_statistics  ... west_load_forecast_entsoe_transparency
utc_timestamp        cet_cest_timestamp                                            ...                                  
2004-12-31T23:00:00Z 2005-01-01T00:00:00+0100                                 NaN  ...                                    NaN
2005-01-01T00:00:00Z 2005-01-01T01:00:00+0100                                 NaN  ...                                    NaN
2005-01-01T01:00:00Z 2005-01-01T02:00:00+0100                                 NaN  ...                                    NaN
2005-01-01T02:00:00Z 2005-01-01T03:00:00+0100                                 NaN  ...                                    NaN
2005-01-01T03:00:00Z 2005-01-01T04:00:00+0100                                 NaN  ...                                    NaN
...                                                                           ...  ...                                    ...
2019-04-30T19:00:00Z 2019-04-30T21:00:00+0200                                 NaN  ...                                  487.0
2019-04-30T20:00:00Z 2019-04-30T22:00:00+0200                                 NaN  ...                                  447.0
2019-04-30T21:00:00Z 2019-04-30T23:00:00+0200                                 NaN  ...                                  410.0
2019-04-30T22:00:00Z 2019-05-01T00:00:00+0200                                 NaN  ...                                  400.0
2019-04-30T23:00:00Z 2019-05-01T01:00:00+0200                                 NaN  ...                                    NaN

[125593 rows x 391 columns]


In [7]: df['AL']
Out[7]:
                                               load_actual_entsoe_power_statistics
utc_timestamp        cet_cest_timestamp
2004-12-31T23:00:00Z 2005-01-01T00:00:00+0100                                  NaN
2005-01-01T00:00:00Z 2005-01-01T01:00:00+0100                                  NaN
2005-01-01T01:00:00Z 2005-01-01T02:00:00+0100                                  NaN
2005-01-01T02:00:00Z 2005-01-01T03:00:00+0100                                  NaN
2005-01-01T03:00:00Z 2005-01-01T04:00:00+0100                                  NaN
...                                                                            ...
2019-04-30T19:00:00Z 2019-04-30T21:00:00+0200                                  NaN
2019-04-30T20:00:00Z 2019-04-30T22:00:00+0200                                  NaN
2019-04-30T21:00:00Z 2019-04-30T23:00:00+0200                                  NaN
2019-04-30T22:00:00Z 2019-05-01T00:00:00+0200                                  NaN
2019-04-30T23:00:00Z 2019-05-01T01:00:00+0200                                  NaN

[125593 rows x 1 columns]
```

Comment: This works! I can use the multilevel index and create dataframes for i in my abbv list if I need to. I really just wanted to extract country by country data at the moment though, so this works!

Comment: This is a great solution.  +1